# Biography on Rav Hirsch

Tags: history, product-recommendation, books-generally, samson-raphael-hirsch

Anyone know of any good (i.e. non-hagiographical) biographies on Rav Samson Rafael Hirsch zt"l?

Comment: The open/closure of this post is a topic of discussion here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96807/discussion-between-b-a-and-double-aa

Comment: This question is [being discussed on Meta](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5175/170).

Answer (score 5):

[Here's (PDF)](http://personal.stevens.edu/~llevine/rsrh_ladies_talk.pdf) an interesting essay-length one that was recently forwarded to me.

Comment: Do you see any way this question is on topic?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.hhjudaica.com/rabbi-samson-raphael-hirsch.html

I. Grunfeld, Three Generations: The Influence of Samson Raphael Hirsch on Jewish Life and Thought (1958)

J. L. Blau, Modern Varieties of Judaism (1966).

Comment: I said non-hagiographical though...this is an Artscroll biography.

Comment: @MatthewMiller The Klugmann is a pretty well-researched and balanced work.

Answer (score 0):

Though their biographies are indeed usually hagiographical, [Artscroll's biography on Rav Hirsch](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/rsrh.html) is actually full of very detailed and accurate information.